# Is there any difference between <span> and <b> with a well-specified CSS class?

Tags: css, html

Essentially, my question is, what is the difference between the two lines in the body of this HTML document?

```
<html>
<head>
 <style>
  .test {color:green; font-weight:normal}
 </style>
</head>
<body>

<b class="test">Test with b tag</b><br />
<span class="test">Test with span tag</span><br />


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is the <p> for trailing each of the lines?  Just curious?

Comment: Semantics, my friend. Aesthetics, not so much.

Comment: The <p> is just to get them to be on separate lines, I guess I should have used <br /> instead.

Comment: I guess this applies to almost all HTML elements.. They are all the same if you style them the way you like, and remove all the default styles.  But it is not a good idea to do so.

Answer (score 4):

The `<b>` (or even better `<strong>`) contains semantic information that the text should be highlighted (printed in bold). `<span>` doesn't have the same connotation to it. If you disable the CSS styles from the document you'll see the `<b>` text still in bold, but the `<span>` in normal text.

The distinction is important especially to screen readers that (often) can convey the information to the user. Using spans with classes carry no such information through.

This doesn't mean that you should always use `<strong>` or `<em>`: if the purpose is purely stylistic and you're not emphasizing text, it's better to use classes.

Comment: Not completely true: <b> is not a semantic tag. <strong> sure is a semantic. They both print the text in bold, but strong is semantic (gives the text more meaning) en <b> is just a style tag.
I never use <b>

Answer (score 2):

`<b>` and `<strong>` have the semantic meaning "should be displayed in bold" while `<span>` is a general-purpose inline element.

But from a technical point of view there are no real differences between those elements if the proper CSS is applied.

Comment: `<b>` is not and has never been deprecated in any version of HTML.

Comment: <b> and <strong> looks the same in the browser, but <b> is a style tag, <strong> is a semantic tag that gives the text more meaning

Answer (score 2):

As per there functionally there is no such difference but there are some differences like this `<b>` use to generally `bold` the text without define `font-weight:bold` in css.It's easily print text in `bold`. But for `<span>` you have to define CSS.

Now the question which one is good. My answer is **span** because **span** was created for multiply styling but other tags like `<b>`, `<strong>`, `<i>`, `<em>` etc are created for represent attribute without using style. So, for an systematic mark if you only want to `bold` the  text then `<b>` is good but if you want other properties like `bold`, `italic`,`color` etc. Then it's better to use .

As per [W3C](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/b.html)

> The b element represents a span of text offset from its surrounding
>   content without conveying any extra emphasis or importance, and for
>   which the conventional typographic presentation is bold text; for
>   example, keywords in a document abstract, or product names in a
>   review.

Answer (score 0):

They might look different, because they have default styles applied to them.  Since your not removing all the styles before adding your styles, they will look different.  And might also look different between browsers.